# Javascript: "undefined" value for variable

Tags: javascript, function, scope, undefined

newbee to Javascript...

I've got a problem with updating a global variable witht he result of a function. When I output the variable it says '***undefined***'.

What I am trying to do is loop though an array (***problemArr***) and create a string in to a variable (***stringA***).

Then add **stringA** to another variable ***stringMessage*** and output the value of stringMessage.

Eg: Your biggest problems are : Prob1, Prob2, Prob3,

I already have an array called problemArr which gets updated from another function which I haven't included in this snippet of code. (This part works I'm able to demonstrate that the array gets updated).

I've read a few posts on here about Function Scope and hoisting, which I think may have something to do with it. Not sure.

```
var stringA = ' ';//initialize variable which will form list of problems 

var stringMessage ='Your biggest problems are :' + stringA; // Output

var problemArr[]; //Empty array. Gets elements from another function - this part works, I've checked. 

//create list of problems
function messageString(){

    for(i in problemArr){

        stringA = stringA + problemArr[i] + ',';
    }

    return stringA;

}
```

Comment: `problemArr` does not exist anywhere, start by defining it or passing it to the function.

Comment: The code doesn't output anything. You are also not calling `messageString`. Why don't you provide a **complete** example?

Comment: where is `problemArr`?

Comment: Is problemArr also a global variable?  Where is the array defined?

Comment: problemArr is defined globally outside of any functions.

Comment: Assuming your `problemArr` is already defined, why don't you do `var stringMessage ='Your biggest problems are :' + messageString();` instead of `var stringMessage ='Your biggest problems are :' + stringA;`? You are setting the `stringMessage` with the current value of `stringA` when you define it and `stringMessage` won't change despite you are changing it on your loop.

Comment: What language is `var problemArr[];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your array it is missng,  then call the function you have created as follows.

```js
var stringA = ' ';//initialize variable which will form list of problems 

var problemArr = ['1','2','3']; // <<<<<<<<< define the array

//create list of problems
function messageString(){

    for(i in problemArr){

        stringA += problemArr[i] ; 
        
        // do not add a comma after the last array item
        if(i < problemArr.length - 1)
        {
           stringA  += ',';
        }
    }

}

messageString(); // <<<<<<<<< call the function

var stringMessage ='Your biggest problems are :' + stringA; // Output

document.write(stringMessage);
```

**Edit**

To match your case, call the function to create the message string and fill `stringA`, then set it to the final output afterward `var stringMessage ='Your biggest problems are :' + stringA; // Output`

Comment: What's wrong with `stringA = stringA + problemArr[i] + ',';`? *Not* using `+=` is perfectly fine. The OP certainly does not *need* to use it.

Comment: Why are you writing to the document?

Comment: writing just to view the result, @FelixKling I have edited the post

Answer (score 1):

trying to replace a string with a string, strings always have to be a new variable, so rather than stringA = stringA you'd need newString = stringA + ","

i've refactored your code, and this will do what you want it to do:

```
(function () {
    var stringA;
    var stringMessage = "Your biggest problems are : ";
    var problemArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

    for (var i = 0; i < problemArr.length; i++) {
        stringA = problemArr[i] + ",";
        stringMessage += stringA;
    }

    alert(stringMessage);

})()
```

the "+=" operator appends something to an existing object
e.g `1 += 2` would equal 3
e.g `"hello" += "world"` would equal "helloworld"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're just trying to add the content of an array to a string variable. Why don't you just do it like this:

```
var problemArr = ["99 problems","but a b****","ain't one"];
//or just use the array you created before

var problemsAsString = problemArr.join(", ");
//converts the array to a string and puts a ", " between each element

var stringMessage = 'Your biggest problems are : ' + problemsAsString; 

alert(stringMessage); //output, or do whatever you want with it
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nvd8jnum/1)